# How to test data for log-normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Can data be log-normally distributed by not normally?

Comment: The usual way is to estimate the parameters with the given data and apply a chi-squared test to look how good the data fits to the resulting distribution. Can (apart from trivial cases like a constant variable) a variable be distributed both log-normal and normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable $X$ has a log-normal distribution if and only if $\log(X)$ has a normal distribution, so to test wheter data is log-normally distributed, you can simply test wheter the log-transformed data is normally distributed.

*"Can data be log-normally distributed by not normally?"*

Yes of course! In fact it is impossible (apart for the trivial case of a constant) for a variable to be both log-normally and normally distributed at the same time, since the normal distribution can take both negative and positive values, but the log-normal distribution can only take positive values.